# How to use bquote with format?

Tags: r

How can I learn how to use bquote with format?  Everything I've seen has been a one off solution to a specific problem.  I would like to annotate a graph with a descriptive title using greek letters, values from my source code, and formats that include the percent sign.

Comment: Could probably do with a bit more info and code to outline exactly what you are trying to do and what you want your final annotation to look like...

Comment: Have you looked at  `?plotmath` ?